# Plotting a dataframe derived from a CSV file (with specific times)

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, plot

I have a lot of data that I need to analyze, but I encounter some problems. Quick note, I am a beginner in Python so it might not be the most complex question.

I have a set of dates and a set of timestamps.

Layout: YYYY:MM:DD       HH:MM:SS:mmm

All rows are in this layout

I want to make a graph per day where I count the amount of timestamps per hour.
If for example I have 4 timestamps from 0800 to 0900, I want a value of 4 between 8 and 9.

The dataset contains ove 20k timestamps over 40 days so for now, I want to make a graph, one for every day.

I read a lot about importing a .csv file using pd.read_csv('test2.csv', etc..) and using that dataframe for my plot. I tried to group all the timestamps per hour and day but that is where it goes wrong.

The problem I encounter is that I cannot use the time as a timestamp because the milliseconds are also added so it does not see it as time (I guess?)

I also found the package seaborn, where displot() was used. For me I do not know what I am reading (yet) but want to learn more coding. Is this a helpful tool?

I know it is not much and I do not have a lot of code, but I have no clue which commands to use, since the layout of my dataframe is different from the examples previously shown.[values short part of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/289Uo.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you broke this problem down into a short simple data set of time stamp only data. Read that single row of time stamp data into a data frame, and work on that. Just a few rows - say less than 10. And not reading from a file. That should help you manipulate timestamps into a sortable type.

Comment: Thanks @natersoz. The thing is that when I import it, I have no lue if it is a timestamp or a value from a DataFrame. It reads the csv and creates a dataframe wihin my variable explorer. Now I want to delete the milliseconds but the datetime.replace has no solution since 'module datetime has no attribute 'replace' '. I want to delete the microseconds since I think the datetimeindex or groupby does not recognize this. Is this correct?